# Crack appeared on the wall. Just a drywall issue or bigger foundation issue?

Tags: drywall, crack

A little background, the house was built in the 70’s and remodeled back in 2006, before we bought the house. It’s on a slab foundation and one story. Probably pretty difficult to tell, but would love some opinions on this crack. Appeared a lot smaller and is growing downward to the left. The other side is a bathroom with a bath, but no leak that is visibly apparent. I know some structural engineers are charging upwards of $400 for a visit, so I thought maybe I’d get some opinions from someone who might have seen this before before I give them a call. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: it's not a drywall issue, that's a stress crack (torsion). that said, it might be seasonal and of no concern. if the right side of the picture is closer to the center of your house, i would be less concerned than vice-versa. check your supports in the basement, see if they still align well. it's a big crack, but not quite big enough to scare me into spending $400. if it gets much worse, or if doesn't self-close this spring, i would get someone out.

Comment: Okay thanks. We don’t have a basement and the right side of the crack is closer to the outside than the center. It seems like that crack has slowly been growing for the past few months.

Comment: Big tempatures swings can also cause cracks like if the furnace is shut off in the winter for a weekend while out of town but I agree with dandavis.+

Comment: @dandavis Answers don't belong in the comments. Write it as a proper answer so it can be voted up!